# Mysql Query performance very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

The below query was taking more than 8 min and 900 000 rows processed. it is very slow and affect my product. I can't identify why the query getting slow, all index are set fine.

```
explain SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT (cinfo.CONTACT_ID))
FROM
    cinfo
        INNER JOIN
    LTocMapping ON cinfo.CONTACT_ID = LTocMapping.CONTACT_ID
WHERE
    (((((((((cinfo.COUNTRY LIKE '%Panama%')
        OR (cinfo.COUNTRY LIKE '%PANAMA%'))
        AND (((cinfo.CONTACT_EMAIL NOT LIKE '%test%')
        AND (cinfo.CONTACT_EMAIL NOT LIKE '%engine%'))
        OR (cinfo.CONTACT_EMAIL IS NULL)))
        AND ((SELECT 
            (GROUP_CONCAT(Temp.LIST_ID
                    ORDER BY Temp.LIST_ID) REGEXP ('.*,*221715000514445053,*.*$'))
            FROM
                LTocMapping Temp
            WHERE
                ((LTocMapping.CONTACT_ID = Temp.CONTACT_ID)
                    AND (((Temp.MAPPING_ID >= 221715000000000000)
                    AND (Temp.MAPPING_ID <= 221715999999999999))
                    OR ((Temp.MAPPING_ID >= 0)
                    AND (Temp.MAPPING_ID <= 999999999999))))
            GROUP BY Temp.CONTACT_ID) = '0'))
        AND ((SELECT 
            (GROUP_CONCAT(Temp.LIST_ID
                    ORDER BY Temp.LIST_ID) REGEXP ('.*,*221715000520574130,*.*$'))
            FROM
                LTocMapping Temp
            WHERE
                ((LTocMapping.CONTACT_ID = Temp.CONTACT_ID)
                    AND (((Temp.MAPPING_ID >= 221715000000000000)
                    AND (Temp.MAPPING_ID <= 221715999999999999))
                    OR ((Temp.MAPPING_ID >= 0)
                    AND (Temp.MAPPING_ID <= 999999999999))))
            GROUP BY Temp.CONTACT_ID) = '0'))
        AND (LTocMapping.LIST_ID IN (221715000520574130 , 221715000201569885)))
        AND (LTocMapping.STATUS = BINARY 'subscribed'))
        AND (((cinfo.CONTACT_STATUS = BINARY 'active')
        OR (cinfo.CONTACT_STATUS = BINARY 'softbounce'))
        AND (LTocMapping.STATUS = BINARY 'subscribed')))
        AND (((cinfo.CONTACT_ID >= 221715000000000000)
        AND (cinfo.CONTACT_ID <= 221715999999999999))
        OR ((cinfo.CONTACT_ID >= 0)
        AND (cinfo.CONTACT_ID <= 999999999999))))
```

And the answer will be

[image]

Below tables FYR

Table 1 :

```
mysql> desc cinfo;
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+-----------+-------+
| Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default   | Extra |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+-----------+-------+
| CONTACT_ID             | bigint(19)   | NO   | PRI | NULL      |       |
| CONTACT_EMAIL          | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL      |       |
| TITLE                  | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL      |       |
| FIRSTNAME              | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL      |       |
| LASTNAME               | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL      |       |     |
| ADDED_BY               | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL      |       |
| ADDED_TIME             | bigint(19)   | NO   |     | NULL      |       |
| LAST_UPDATED_TIME      | bigint(19)   | NO   |     | NULL      |       |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+-----------+-------+
```

Table 2 :

```
 mysql> desc LTocMapping;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default    | Extra |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| MAPPING_ID          | bigint(19)   | NO   | PRI | NULL       |       |
| CONTACT_ID          | bigint(19)   | NO   | MUL | NULL       |       |
| LIST_ID             | bigint(19)   | NO   | MUL | NULL       |       |
| STATUS              | varchar(100) | YES  |     | subscribed |       |
| MAPPING_STATUS      | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | connected  |       |
| MAPPING_TIME        | bigint(19)   | YES  |     | NULL       |       |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
```

Comment: Are you really coding / looking at SQL that looks like that or did you just decide that it would be otherwise too easy for us to help you?

Comment: Bug:  In searching for `LIKE %Guinea%`, you will also get "Guinea-Bissau".  Ditto for Niger and Nigeria.  And probably others.

Answer (score 0):

As Far as I can tell, your subqueries are the bottleneck:

- For the first subquery, you are using `LTocMapping.CONTACT_ID`
- For the second subquery, you are using `LTocMapping.CONTACT_ID` as well.

These references (to values of the outer query) are causing these inner queries to become `correlated subqueries` (also called `dependent subqueries`). And that means: For every row you are going to fetch on one of the outer tables (~970000) - you are firing 2 additional queries on another table.

So, that's 1.8 Million (as it seems as well not trivial) queries you are executing.

Most the time, a correlated subquery can be replaced by a proper join. But this depends on the usecase.  You also can join the same table twice, when using a different alias.

But to outline some join-options, you need to explain, why the subqueries resulting in the condition `group_concat(....) = '0'` are important - or maybe better, what you want to achieve.

(ps.: You can also see, that `explain` outlines them as `dependent subquery`)

Answer (score 0):

`OR` is inefficient, see if you can avoid it.

Leading wildcards in `LIKE` are inefficient.  See if a `FULLTEXT` index would work for you.

With a proper `COLLATION`, you don't need to test both upper and lower case.  Also you can avoid use of `BINARY`.  In both cases, you might be able to use an index.  (What indexes do you have?)

Try to change from

```
WHERE ( ( SELECT ... ) = '0' )
```

to

```
WHERE ( NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ... ) )
```

(The `SELECT` will need some modification.)

(Please get rid of some of the redundant parens; it is hard to read.)

(Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.)