# SELECT MAX with WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to execute following sql query

```
SELECT MAX(amount) AS LargestPrice FROM au_bids WHERE product = 73
```

I'm not able to do this as WHERE condition is not working and it gives me the value of largest number in entire table.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: An error-message would help us to help you..

Comment: in my opinion all is ok

Comment: Please post the data you execute the statement on (example content of au_bids), and the result you get back.

Comment: when u select without max does the where filter work?

Comment: Does product 73 also happen to be the most expensive?

Comment: try SELECT amount AS LargestPrice FROM au_bids WHERE product = 73 ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 1

Answer (score 2):

Your Query Is Correct

```
SELECT MAX(amount) AS LargestPrice FROM au_bids WHERE product = 73
```

Check Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11bbf1/2

Comment: Thanks friend. I was pretty sure that it was correct as well, but still WHERE condition is not working. Maybe something wrong with MYSQL version? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Welcome if you got your answer you can accept @SerginistO

Answer (score 0):

your query is corrct

```
mysql> select * from Customers;
+-------------+---------------+
| customer_id | customer_name |
+-------------+---------------+
|           1 | Arun          |
|           2 | kumar         |
|           4 | bbbbb         |
|           5 | mmmmm         |
|           6 | kkkk          |
|           3 | eeeeee        |
+-------------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select max(customer_id) from Customers where customer_id=2;
+------------------+
| max(customer_id) |
+------------------+
|                2 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I didn't saw your answer sorry 
please find my question and help me to findout the issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536353/mysql-query-performance-very-slow